# VBA to set cell contents as Named range name

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to set the first 7 characters of the first cell in a range to be a named ranges name IF the cell begins with the word "kit".

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub DefineRanges()
Dim rngStart As Range
Set rngStart = Range("A1")
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim RangeName As String

For Each cell In Range("A2:A7")
    If LCase(Left(cell.Value, 3)) = "kit" Then

        RangeName = LCase(Left(cell.Value, 7))

        ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add _
            Name:=RangeName, _
            RefersToLocal:=Range(rngStart.Address & ":C" & cell.Row - 1)
        Set rngStart = Range("A" & cell.Row)

    End If
    LastRow = cell.Row
Next
RangeName = LCase(Left(cell.Value, 7))

ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add _
    Name:=RangeName, _
    RefersToLocal:=Range(rngStart.Address & ":C" & LastRow)
End Sub
```

Essentially I want it to look through my overall Range, find any cells that begin with the word "kit", create a named range that goes from that cell until the next cell that begins with "kit", and assign the first 7 characters of that cell to be the ranges name. So far I am able to get it to create the ranges, but I run into issues when I try to pass the contents of the cell into the range name. Any ideas?

Comment: what error message do you get and on which line?

Comment: It just gives me a 400 error message. It seems like my problem is with                                                                                                    RangeName = LCase(Left(cell.Value, 7)) . I know It sets the variable because I had it paste the output in a different cell, but for some reason it wont let me pass that variable into the range name

Comment: You are trying to refer to `cell` outside the loop this is why the error.

Comment: ^^^ cell becomes nothing after the For Each loop

Comment: Why do you repeat the lines outside the loop that are also inside?

Comment: You'll run into issues if any cells contains errors, or if any cell's contents is less than 7 characters. Other problems are to be expected if the `ActiveSheet` isn't the expected/intended worksheet, and if the names are already defined. And without `Option Explicit` specified you'll quickly run into other problems, harder to diagnose. Always use `Option Explicit`.

Comment: I had those in there originally for the last range. I know its kind of a messy way of doing it but it was the best I could think of as I researched lol. Thank you guys!

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Mat'sMug . I see how those things could become an issue once you start changing the data/ spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes that you data is similar to your last question.

It uses Match to find each `"Kit..."` saving a few iterations:

```
Sub DefineRanges()
Dim rngStart As Long
Dim RangeName As String
Dim col As Long
Dim PreFx As String

col = 1 'change to the column number you need
PreFx = "kat" 'change to the prefix you are looking for

With Worksheets("Sheet7") 'change to your sheet
    On Error Resume Next
        rngStart = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(PreFx & "*", .Columns(col), 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rngStart > 0 Then
        Do
            i = 0
            On Error Resume Next
                i = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(PreFx & "*", .Range(.Cells(rngStart + 1, col), .Cells(.Rows.Count, col)), 0) + rngStart
            On Error GoTo 0
            If i > 0 Then
                RangeName = LCase(Left(.Cells(rngStart, col).Value, 7))
                ActiveWorkbook.names.Add name:=RangeName, RefersToLocal:=.Range(.Cells(rngStart, col), .Cells(i - 1, col + 2))
                rngStart = i
            Else 'no more "kit..." so find the last row with data and use that
                i = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("zzz", .Columns(col))
                RangeName = LCase(Left(.Cells(rngStart, 1).Value, 7))
                ActiveWorkbook.names.Add name:=RangeName, RefersToLocal:=.Range(.Cells(rngStart, col), .Cells(i - 1, col + 2))

            End If
        Loop While i < Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("zzz", .Columns(col))
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: `If rngStart Then` reads like a hack. The implicit `Long`-to-`Boolean` conversion might not be obvious to a rookie here.

Comment: @Mat'sMug are you saying I should `rngstart>0` or just explain it?

Comment: I'd go with `If rngStart > 0 Then`, yeah. Otherwise great answer - all that's missing is an `IsError` and length check on the cell values, to avoid blowing up when `#N/A` is encountered, or if `KitKat` is in there.

Comment: But the match will not find an error and I am only doing the Left on the cell the match returned.  I do not understand how `KitKat` would be a problem, this is a true question, as I am not seeing it. @Mat'sMug

Comment: Nevermind, VBA is happy with taking the 7 leftmost characters of a 6-character string. C# wouldn't be ;-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug that's why I specifically used `kittes` just to make sure.  I almost did the whole `IIF(LEN()<7,LEN(),7)` before remembering.

Comment: wow that worked perfectly! Ok so that answer is a lot better written than what I had originally...Definitely gives me a lot to look at and learn. (Still super new to VBA but learning a bit every day) Thank you so much for taking the time to do this. Everyone's help is greatly appreciated. Thanks again!

Comment: why does Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("zzz" .... find the last row? i have seen it used elsewhere and i can guess it is for text and to do with z being the last letter of the alphabet but i am still unsure why? Same as 1e99 for numbers? Sorry if a dumb question.

Comment: @QHarr stepped into a meeting will come back after and explain

Comment: @QHarr MATCH with the missing third argument tries to find where the lookup value is >= and < the next value in the range.  By putting impossibly big values to search for `"zzz"` for text and `1e+99` for numbers it goes through the list and never finds anyone that is greater than the search value, so it automatically returns the last value in the list.

Comment: @ScottCraner Many thanks for explaining. I have used the 1e+99 without ever questioning and since coming onto SO have seen "zzz" being used.

Comment: @QHarr "zzz" will return the last used Text cell and 1e+99 the last used number cell.  To find the true last if they are mixed one would need to use `max(match("zzz",...),match(1e+99,...)` If it is unkown an could be either or and one needs to wrap each match in iferror: `IFERROR(MATCH("zzz",...),0)` inside the max to deal with if there are only numbers but could have text.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you. That has gone straight into my bag of tricks so to speak.